# cloudformation sample template for for aws dms

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation, dms

I am new to the cloudformation.I had used the dms on the aws console but i need to create a dms service task using cloudformation.I saw templates for other servies but not for dms.My source db is postgres which is in ec2 and migrating to RDS.i didnt find any tempolate.looking for sample template for AWS Data migration Systems.I an new to cloudformations.Can anybody help here.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example. https://hands-on.cloud/aws-cloudformation-how-to-create-dms-infrastructure-for-relational-db-migration/.

I usually find the official documentation to be useful too. For each resource type, the documentation provides both JSON and YAML format and detailed specification. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_DMS.html.